# Get first row from query results.

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to get the data from the first row of the query results.

Here's my current code (USERNAME = column name):

```
userName.InnerHtml = DBresult.DataSet.Tables(0).Rows(0)("USERNAME").ToString()
```

Here's the error I get:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: you need an if condition to check if DBresult is null, if DataSet is null, if DataSet.Tables is null

Comment: So you have 5 possible reasons: `DBresult` is null, `DataSet` is null, there is no table in the DataSet, there are no rows in the first table, `USERNAME` is a nullable field. Have you asked  the debugger?

Comment: You should be able to figure out *what* is `null`. In fact, **only you** can.

Comment: Thanks guys. Problem was simple; DBresult was null !! 
I need some coffee !

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.  Even though Cstr is the old way.

```
Dim i as Integer
For i = 0 To DBresult.DataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1 
  If IsDBNull(DBresult.DataSet.Tables(0).Rows(i)("USERNAME")) = True Then
'Do something
Else
  userName.InnerHtml = Cstr(DBresult.DataSet.Tables(0).Rows(i)("USERNAME"))
```